# How to play only one video among different videos in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video

I'm using Angularjs to build a web application ! the problem i'm facing that I can't stop the other videos when one is playing.

For example this is my controller :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.video1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/wsXWjj88vKo';
    $scope.video2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/FVXajf9ALPM';
}
```

and this my html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<iframe  ng-src="{{video1}}" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe  ng-src="{{video2}}" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there any way to add a button to stop the other videos from playing, or stop or refresh or reload the other videos when one is playing

Here is the [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14550/)

Answer (score 0):

use controller like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<iframe  ng-src="{{video1}}" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
<button ng-click='clickme()'>Change Video</button>
</div>
```

and your view like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.video1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/wsXWjj88vKo';
        $scope.clickme = function(){
            $scope.video1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/FVXajf9ALPM';
        }   
    }
```

Cheers!

## EDIT:

Or Please refer: below link

http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-03-video/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this doesn't help a lot ! I want to click on a button a all videos stop

Comment: Can you specify, How exactly you want? 
Means is it by click? or setting some timeout to change URL ?

Comment: I wanna keep both videos, I don't want to change video link, I want to be able to play only one video, I want to disable the ability to play both on the same tilme

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want

Comment: Sorry Friend! You need to use any plugin or JS for this purpose. HTML5 doesnt support like this

Comment: Please check my answer now. Posted again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your final answer:

You must use any plugin/JS for this purpose. 
I can suggeest you **jplayer** for it.

Please refer: below link

http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-03-video/

Hope I helped you now.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but that doesn't help I want to have the same youtube videos